# ffmpeg connection to tcp://localhost failed

Tags: ffmpeg

I've spent days going over google and serverfault ffmpeg questions, and I can't figure out why I get this error:

```
[tcp @ 0x357230] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
```

It will work with 127.0.0.1, but I want to access this feed from my home network.

Most answers on the net point to adding this line in the feed1 and stream1 section:

```
ACL allow locahost
```

or these lines in the feed1 and stream1 section:

```
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
```

NO LUCK.

I've made sure I have restarted the ffserver every time.
I have no errors in the ffserver.conf, and confirmed it is loading the correct /etc/ffserver.conf
I've tried a fresh install using Debian Jessie Armbian.
I've tried and a fresh install using Ubuntu 16 LTS Armbian.
It is an Arm device..

There is no ethernet port, only a working wifi.

There is no firewall.

ffmpeg -version

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2
```

ffserver.ini

```
# Port on which the server is listening. You must select a different
# port from your standard HTTP web server if it is running on the same
# computer.
HTTPPort 8090

# Address on which the server is bound. Only useful if you have
# several network interfaces.
# HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

# Number of simultaneous HTTP connections that can be handled. It has
# to be defined *before* the MaxClients parameter, since it defines the
# MaxClients maximum limit.
MaxHTTPConnections 2000

# Number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. Since FFServer
# is very fast, it is more likely that you will want to leave this high
# and use MaxBandwidth, below.
MaxClients 1000

# This the maximum amount of kbit/sec that you are prepared to
# consume when streaming to clients.
MaxBandwidth 1000

# Access log file (uses standard Apache log file format)
# '-' is the standard output.
CustomLog -

##################################################################
# Definition of the live feeds. Each live feed contains one video
# and/or audio sequence coming from an ffmpeg encoder or another
# ffserver. This sequence may be encoded simultaneously with several
# codecs at several resolutions.

<Feed feed1.ffm>

# You must use 'ffmpeg' to send a live feed to ffserver. In this
# example, you can type:
#
# ffmpeg http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

# ffserver can also do time shifting. It means that it can stream any
# previously recorded live stream. The request should contain:
# "http://xxxx?date=[YYYY-MM-DDT][[HH:]MM:]SS[.m...]".You must specify
# a path where the feed is stored on disk. You also specify the
# maximum size of the feed, where zero means unlimited. Default:
# File=/tmp/feed_name.ffm FileMaxSize=5M
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200K

# You could specify
# ReadOnlyFile /saved/specialvideo.ffm
# This marks the file as readonly and it will not be deleted or updated.

# Specify launch in order to start ffmpeg automatically.
# First ffmpeg must be defined with an appropriate path if needed,
# after that options can follow, but avoid adding the http:// field
#Launch ffmpeg

# Only allow connections from localhost to the feed.
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>


##################################################################
# Now you can define each stream which will be generated from the
# original audio and video stream. Each format has a filename (here
# 'test1.mpg'). FFServer will send this stream when answering a
# request containing this filename.

<Stream test1.avi>

# coming from live feed 'feed1'
Feed feed1.ffm

# Format of the stream : you can choose among:
# mpeg       : MPEG-1 multiplexed video and audio
# mpegvideo  : only MPEG-1 video
# mp2        : MPEG-2 audio (use AudioCodec to select layer 2 and 3 codec)
# ogg        : Ogg format (Vorbis audio codec)
# rm         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Multiplexed audio and video.
# ra         : RealNetworks-compatible stream. Audio only.
# mpjpeg     : Multipart JPEG (works with Netscape without any plugin)
# jpeg       : Generate a single JPEG image.
# mjpeg      : Generate a M-JPEG stream.
# asf        : ASF compatible streaming (Windows Media Player format).
# swf        : Macromedia Flash compatible stream
# avi        : AVI format (MPEG-4 video, MPEG audio sound)
Format avi

# Bitrate for the audio stream. Codecs usually support only a few
# different bitrates.
AudioBitRate 32

# Number of audio channels: 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
AudioChannels 1

# Sampling frequency for audio. When using low bitrates, you should
# lower this frequency to 22050 or 11025. The supported frequencies
# depend on the selected audio codec.
AudioSampleRate 44100

# Bitrate for the video stream
VideoBitRate 128

# Ratecontrol buffer size
VideoBufferSize 40

# Number of frames per second
VideoFrameRate 15

# Size of the video frame: WxH (default: 160x128)
# The following abbreviations are defined: sqcif, qcif, cif, 4cif, qqvga,
# qvga, vga, svga, xga, uxga, qxga, sxga, qsxga, hsxga, wvga, wxga, wsxga,
# wuxga, woxga, wqsxga, wquxga, whsxga, whuxga, cga, ega, hd480, hd720,
# hd1080
VideoSize 620x480

# Transmit only intra frames (useful for low bitrates, but kills frame rate).
#VideoIntraOnly

# If non-intra only, an intra frame is transmitted every VideoGopSize
# frames. Video synchronization can only begin at an intra frame.
VideoGopSize 12

# More MPEG-4 parameters
# VideoHighQuality
# Video4MotionVector

# Choose your codecs:
#AudioCodec mp2
#VideoCodec mpeg1video

# Suppress audio
NoAudio

# Suppress video
#NoVideo

#VideoQMin 3
#VideoQMax 31

# Set this to the number of seconds backwards in time to start. Note that
# most players will buffer 5-10 seconds of video, and also you need to allow
# for a keyframe to appear in the data stream.
#Preroll 15

# ACL:

# You can allow ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
#ACL ALLOW <first address> <last address>
ACL ALLOW 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
ACL ALLOW localhost

# You can deny ranges of addresses (or single addresses)
#ACL DENY <first address> <last address>

# You can repeat the ACL allow/deny as often as you like. It is on a per
# stream basis. The first match defines the action. If there are no matches,
# then the default is the inverse of the last ACL statement.
#
# Thus 'ACL allow localhost' only allows access from localhost.
# 'ACL deny 1.0.0.0 1.255.255.255' would deny the whole of network 1 and
# allow everybody else.

</Stream>


##################################################################
# Example streams


# Multipart JPEG

#<Stream test.mjpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mpjpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Single JPEG

#<Stream test.jpg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format jpeg
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
##VideoSize 352x240
#NoAudio
#Strict -1
#</Stream>


# Flash

#<Stream test.swf>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format swf
#VideoFrameRate 2
#VideoIntraOnly
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# ASF compatible

<Stream test.asf>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format asf
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 352x240
VideoBitRate 256
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 30
AudioBitRate 64
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>


# MP3 audio

#<Stream test.mp3>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format mp2
#AudioCodec mp3
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 1
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Ogg Vorbis audio

#<Stream test.ogg>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Metadata title "Stream title"
#AudioBitRate 64
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 44100
#NoVideo
#</Stream>


# Real with audio only at 32 kbits

#<Stream test.ra>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#NoVideo
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


# Real with audio and video at 64 kbits

#<Stream test.rm>
#Feed feed1.ffm
#Format rm
#AudioBitRate 32
#VideoBitRate 128
#VideoFrameRate 25
#VideoGopSize 25
#NoAudio
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# A stream coming from a file: you only need to set the input
# filename and optionally a new format. Supported conversions:
#    AVI -> ASF

#<Stream file.rm>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/tlive.rm"
#NoAudio
#</Stream>

#<Stream file.asf>
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test.asf"
#NoAudio
#Metadata author "Me"
#Metadata copyright "Super MegaCorp"
#Metadata title "Test stream from disk"
#Metadata comment "Test comment"
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# RTSP examples
#
# You can access this stream with the RTSP URL:
#   rtsp://localhost:5454/test1-rtsp.mpg
#
# A non-standard RTSP redirector is also created. Its URL is:
#   http://localhost:8090/test1-rtsp.rtsp

#<Stream test1-rtsp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#</Stream>


# Transcode an incoming live feed to another live feed,
# using libx264 and video presets

#<Stream live.h264>
#Format rtp
#Feed feed1.ffm
#VideoCodec libx264
#VideoFrameRate 24
#VideoBitRate 100
#VideoSize 480x272
#AVPresetVideo default
#AVPresetVideo baseline
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
#
#AudioCodec libfaac
#AudioBitRate 32
#AudioChannels 2
#AudioSampleRate 22050
#AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
#</Stream>

##################################################################
# SDP/multicast examples
#
# If you want to send your stream in multicast, you must set the
# multicast address with MulticastAddress. The port and the TTL can
# also be set.
#
# An SDP file is automatically generated by ffserver by adding the
# 'sdp' extension to the stream name (here
# http://localhost:8090/test1-sdp.sdp). You should usually give this
# file to your player to play the stream.
#
# The 'NoLoop' option can be used to avoid looping when the stream is
# terminated.

#<Stream test1-sdp.mpg>
#Format rtp
#File "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/test1.mpg"
#MulticastAddress 224.124.0.1
#MulticastPort 5000
#MulticastTTL 16
#NoLoop
#</Stream>


##################################################################
# Special streams

# Server status

<Stream stat.html>
Format status

# Only allow local people to get the status
#ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

#FaviconURL http://pond1.gladstonefamily.net:8080/favicon.ico
</Stream>


# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

Comment: this may seem trivial, but have you checked that the port is actually listening?  Also, `ffserver` talks HTTP, your url should be `http://localhost:8090` not `tcp://localhost:8090`

Comment: Hiya, ffmpeg reports 'tcp' even tho the docs and command line specify 'http'.. I've seen it reported this way in my searches. netstat -L shows 8090 listening when ffserver is being run, even before ffmpeg is being run, it is ffmpeg that checks the conf file for ACL and then says it doesn't like local host.

Answer (score 3):

I double checked everything and after a little bit of an epiphany decided that
the "feed" block is an internal only stream, and can only use:

```
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
```

and the "stream" block is the final steam to the network interface, so needs a network range to allow access to:

```
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
```

Why ffmpeg won't allow the word "localhost" is beyond me, it's in all the docs, perhaps now depreciated?

I can now confirm with the above ACL settings, using this command will work on a 192.168.x.x network.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Comment: The "localhost"  problem apparently is a far more fundamental ffmpeg problem. It also fails in rather unrelated contexts, e.g. `ffmpeg -loop 1 - i http://localhost/testImage.png`.

Comment: Excellent, that solved my problem! `localhost` is going to be either `127.0.0.1` or `::1` and many servers (and clients too) do not support that duality. The best for servers is to listen to the IPv6 (`::1`) and that will accept connections to `127.0.0.1` automatically. In that case, for clients, either will work if the server followed that rule.